# Convert between java.time API and java.util.Date

Tags: android, java.util.date, java-time, android-studio-4.0

Starting with Android Studio 4, the great `java.time` API is available to Android.

In my project, I want to migrate gradually from `java.util.Date` to the new API.

How can I convert between the two formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I want to point out the differences, which are severe.

### java.time

The java.time API does a great job in being explicit about different concepts of time, e.g. if you want to represent a certain point in time or a `Duration`. 
In the first case, you can choose if you want to represent a date, time, or both and if you want it to be time zone aware or not, e.g.

- `LocalDate` (date, no time, no time zone)
- `LocalDateTime` (date, time, no time zone)
- `ZonedDateTime` (date, time, time zone)

An `Instant` represents a timestamp (nanoseconds since 01.01.1970 in UTC). So it's a machine representation of time but also a building block for other classes.

To see all classes see the [java.time API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

### java.util.Date

The methods of `Date` suggest it represents a date and time. Internally, it stores only a timestamp (milliseconds since 01.01.1970 UTC) and no time zone.

The recommended way to create it is using the time zone aware `Calendar` class. However, the `Date` itself is generated by implicitly using the time zone the computer is running on.
Calling `toString()` the formatted output might show a time zone but it is obtained externally from a `Calendar` instance, which leads to the confusion `Date` would store a time zone.

All in all, the API is poorly designed and can be confusing. `java.time` is far superior and should be used if available.

### Adapter for Legacy Code

How are the two APIs connected then? -> via `Instant`.

In java 8 `java.util.Date` was extended with two methods:

- `public static Date from(Instant instant)`
- `public Instant toInstant()`

This is the built-in bridge between both APIs!

We can built further adapter functions on top of that.
Here is an example (in Kotlin) with conversion for the classes `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`:

```
/**
 * java.util.Date has no explicit time zone but implicitly uses the system's time zone
 */
private val dateZoneId: ZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault()

fun Date.toLocalDate(): LocalDate = toInstant().atZone(dateZoneId).toLocalDate()

fun LocalDate.toDate(): Date = Date.from(atStartOfDay(dateZoneId).toInstant())

fun Date.toLocalDateTime(): LocalDateTime = toInstant().atZone(dateZoneId).toLocalDateTime()

fun LocalDateTime.toDate(): Date = Date.from(atZone(dateZoneId).toInstant())
```

Comment: "A Date represents a date and time." - Hm, rather not, a `java.util.Date` directly corresponds to an instant measured in milliseconds since Unix epoch. Well, its method `toString()` prints the instant as date and time in the default time zone which causes a lot of confusion.

Comment: Thanks for point this out. I edited the section to clarify that the internal state of `Date` is a timestamp.